# Reading i-cal/ics attributes with line-breaks / line-folding

Tags: php, regex, icalendar

I want to implement i very basic calendar feature in PHP. But the customer wants to be able to import his own calendars from another source. I've got an generic ics file.
I've discovered that sometimes large lines, e.g  Long Descriptions or some apple iCal lines break down to a new line with a whitespace as the first character.

I want to get every single attribute with a regex via preg_match_all.

Here's an example that contains example lines from google and apple attributes as well as an similar description as i got it from the customer.

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20150123T060000Z
DTEND:20150123T070000Z
DTSTAMP:20171027T205827Z
UID:1234567894567890ß6543
CREATED:20150131T171526Z
ORGANIZER;CN=someemail@mail.com:mailto:email@server.com
UID:1234567890
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;CN=So
 me NameX-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:name@server.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;CN=Anoth 
 er Name;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:name@server.com
DESCRIPTION: this is a very long d\nescription. It brea
 ks down if the l\nine is too long. It seems to be quit
 e normal. But it \n also contains \n's.
X-APPLE-STRUCTURED-LOCATION;VALUE=URI;X-APPLE-MAPKIT-HANDLE=CAESmQIaEgnfNH1
 2wAtJQBFuMT83NE0hQCKcAQoLRGV1dHNjaGxhbmQSAkRFGgZIZXNzZW4qEUZyYW5rZnVydCBhbS
 BNYWluMhFGcmFua2Z1cnQgYW0gTWFpbjoFNjA1MjhCBFPDvGRSGUhlaW5yaWNoLUhvZmZtYW5uL
 VN0cmHDn2VaAjEwYhxIZWlucmljaC1Ib2ZmbWFubi1TdHJhw59lIDEwigEJTmllZGVycmFkigEE
 U8O8ZCocSGVpbnJpY2gtSG9mZm1hbm4tU3RyYcOfZSAxMDIcSGVpbnJpY2gtSG9mZm1hbm4tU3R
 yYcOfZSAxMDIXNjA1MjggRnJhbmtmdXJ0IGFtIE1haW4yC0RldXRzY2hsYW5kODlAAA==;X-APP
 LE-RADIUS=49.91306619367188;X-APPLE-REFERENCEFRAME=1;X-TITLE="A location , Frankfurt am Main, Germany":geo:12.345678,9.123456
LAST-MODIFIED:20150131T171526Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY: The Title
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
```

The regex i got seems to work fine for lines that don't continue on the next line:

```
/(((.*?:)(.*?)).*)/
```

for

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20150123T060000Z
DTEND:20150123T070000Z
DTSTAMP:20171027T205827Z
UID:1234567894567890ß6543
CREATED:20150131T171526Z
UID:1234567890
DESCRIPTION: some description
LAST-MODIFIED:20150131T171526Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY: The Title
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
```

gives this:

```
array(5
0   =>  array(15
0   =>  BEGIN:VEVENT
1   =>  DTSTART:20150123T060000Z
2   =>  DTEND:20150123T070000Z
3   =>  DTSTAMP:20171027T205827Z
4   =>  UID:1234567894567890ß6543
5   =>  CREATED:20150131T171526Z
6   =>  UID:1234567890
7   =>  DESCRIPTION: some description
8   =>  LAST-MODIFIED:20150131T171526Z
9   =>  LOCATION:
10  =>  SEQUENCE:0
11  =>  STATUS:CONFIRMED
12  =>  SUMMARY: The Title
13  =>  TRANSP:OPAQUE
14  =>  END:VEVENT
)
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/lXX (preg_match_all)

I can surely work with that, but i can't figure out how to detect line-breaks in attributes that can have any number of line-breaks.
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/lXY (preg_match_all)

Like, for the exact example i provided, following regex seems to work:

```
(DESCRIPTION:(.*))|(X-APPLE(.*?)geo:(.*))|(((.*?:)(.*?)).*)|((.*)\n(.*):mailto:.*)|((.*):mailto:.*)
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/lXW (preg_match_all)

But I can't cover any single case as the runtime would probably explode.

---

#### Solved

I wasn't seeing this from the right perspective.
I'd just have to preg_replace the line breaks away:

```
preg_replace("/\n /", "", $input_lines);
```

It's important to have a whitespace after the \n.
After that, I can just proceed to get any lines properly.

Comment: Do you have to use preg_match_all? Why not use preg_replace, match `\n ` 
 and replace with blank http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/lY0

Comment: FYI: This is called "line folding".  Might help you find a solution.

Comment: Ah, haven't thought of that.  Removing the line folding is actually a great idea and works as i want it. I wish i could upvote your comments.Thanks. 

Maybe someone else will stumble upon this question, so i'll update it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not actually matching an expression, it will run faster as a str_replace rather than preg_replace.

```
$input_lines = str_replace("\n ", "", $input_lines);
```

I think you could speed up the rest of the searching as well by exploding on \n, using strpos to find the first colon and than using substr to get the text before/after it, but that is more function calls so you might want to time that on a large ical file.  If the files are small, it's probably not worth the complexity to re-write that part.